# Preferred method of ceasing execution based on conditional within a method

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS, and still learning the proper ways of how to do things. Another question that just reared its head, how can I cease execution of a method, based on a conditional and return back to calling code? Normally in PHP, I simply return `true`/`false`, or throw an exception, rather than tucking huge blocks of code within nested conditionals, but in iOS, I am not allowed to return from a method with a IBAction return signature.

What would be the preferred way of handling this sitch?

```
- (IBAction)submitCode:(id)sender
{
    if ([codeEntry.text length] == 0) {

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Form Validation"                                                         message:@"No code entered, please try again."
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [message show];

        // IOS not allowing this
        return NO;
    }

    // Prefer not to wrap the rest of the logic in an else, rather just cease
    // execution and return back to calling code

    NSLog(@"I would have submitted!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `return;`, not `return NO;`.

The `IBAction` is really `void`. This means the method has no return value.

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense. Try to avoid null returns, but guess I have to in this case. Another quick question, is if preferred to return TRUE/FALSE or YES/NO?

Comment: It depends on the method's return type. If it is `BOOL`, then use `YES/NO`.

Comment: @rmaddy I've seen both for BOOLs. I bet the compiler just changes TRUE/FALSE to YES/NO.

Comment: You may have seen both but that doesn't make it correct. `BOOL` is meant to be used with `YES/NO`. You may get away with other values but that doesn't mean that using other values is correct.

Comment: @rmaddy But I thought the ends justify the means? Anyway, all normal people use YES/NO for BOOL's, so I bet it was built into the compiler to change TRUE/FALSE into YES/NO for the few stragglers. In the system, it's `1` and `0`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
return;
```

This will stop execution of the current method.

Since `IBAction` is secretly `typdef`'ed to `void`, you can't return anything. Nothing is nothing is nothing, so just use `return;`.